# Check if GET variable is already set

Tags: javascript

I have this code that adds `?prside=5` for example. However, if you change this and the url already is `&prside=5`, it just appends it again (`&prside=5&prside=40`).

How do i update it instead of appending it, if it's already present?

```
<select name="prside" onchange="document.location.href = document.location.href + \'&prside=\' + this.value">
    <option>Annoncer pr. side</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
</select>
```

EDIT:
There is other GET variables in the real URL too. And the above script does work, it's just not very pretty with multiple &prside

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: You might want to look into [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) or [this](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) if you're using jQuery.

Comment: Will there be other GET variables?

Comment: There will be other GET variables, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the existence of prside using the string indexOf method, then you could use a regular expression to replace the value if it exists:

```
href = document.location.href;
if(!~href.indexOf('prside'))
    document.location.href = href + 'prside=' + this.value;
else
    document.location.href = href.replace(/(prside=)\d+/, '$1' + this.value)
```

Here is a one liner if you want to put it straight into the HTML

```
document.location.href = !~document.location.href.indexOf('prside') ? document.location.href + 'prside=' + this.value : document.location.href.replace(/(prside=)\d+/, '$1' + this.value);
```

Comment: This is the base URL: alpha_1/?side=annoncer
When i copy/paste your oneliner, it doesn't do anything if &prside isn't already set.
When it IS set (manually), this is what i get:
alpha_1/?side=annoncer&prside=5prside=20

Comment: Try it now.  I chanced `~` to `!~`